# passing float variable as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, objective-c-runtime

I am trying to write a method with `float` parameter and call it using performSelector` but I am getting error in doing this. Following is my code:

```objectivec
[sender performSelector:selector withObject:progress/total];
```

Here progress and total both are `float` variable.

I am trying to call following method in different class:

```objectivec
-(void) updateProgress:(float)fl {
    
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to pass a real object, not one of the basic types like int or float.

Wrap it into an `NSNumber` object:

```
[sender performSelector:selector withObject:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:progress/total]];

-(void) updateProgress:(NSNumber *)aProgress {
   float fProgress = [aProgress floatValue];
}
```

Comment: this is also right and u can try this also[sender performSelector:selector withObject:(float)(progress/total)];

Comment: @GhostRider: No. A float is something completely different as an NSObject.

Comment: sorry then you can save it in one string and then pass that string in object and then convert it, your way is also good but me never try this with nsnumber me always save in string and pick [string floatValue] when need

Comment: You can encode anything in a string, it just doesn't make sense and can easily lose precision.

Answer (score 1):

It's because `-performSelector:withObject:` only works for *Objective-C objects*. `float` isn't one of these.

Why not just use

```
[(TheClass*)sender updateProgress:progress/total];
```

?

Comment: The naming of the variable makes me think he wants to update UI from a background thread which makes calling on the main thread mandatory.

Comment: Perhaps he is trying to use -performSelector:withObject:afterDelay

Comment: u r correct Eiko, this is what i exactly wanted to do, thanks