# Objective-C, passing float as parameter

Tags: parameters, floating-point, nsnumber

I found this problem, which is very weird.

```
- (void)imageMove:(float)xx y:(NSInteger)yy
{
    NSLog(@"xx=%f,----yy=%d",xx,yy);
}
```

when I call this function: 
    [self imageMove:50 y:50];

the log shows: xx=0.000000,----yy=50

Comment: It works for me. I get: `xx=50.000000,----yy=50`. Show the context of the code itself and the code  that's calling it please.

Comment: You can always try forcing your integer (50) to be a float by adding a specifier: `50.f`.

Comment: If (as you say in your comment below) you fixed the problem by calling http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948255/passing-float-variable-as-parameter, then you did not show your code correctly. You said that you call `[self imageMove:50 y:50]`, but that page implies you are calling some form of `performSelector`. So you misrepresented what you're actually doing. That makes it impossible to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're confusing yourself somehow. When I try doing what you said, I get this:

```
xx=50.000000,----yy=50
```

Since that isn't what you get, you must be doing something different from what you say you're doing. For example, you might be calling `imageMove` from somewhere else that you've forgotten about. Put a breakpoint on your `NSLog` line and work your way back through the call stack to see what's really happening. Also, that way you can see what value `xx` actually has when it arrives as an argument.

Comment: I debugged like you said, but xx=0.000000, I fixed my problem from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948255/passing-float-variable-as-parameter, I just don't know why I can't use float as parameter. thx.